# Coin toss class returning the same side up everytime

Tags: java, random

I need help. I am supposed to run the coin toss 40 times and count each time it is heads and tails, but for some reason it keeps returning either all heads or all tails and I can't figure out why. I have been given a UML diagram that I must follow. It calls for a private String called sideUp, a public no arg constructor called Coin, a public void method called toss, and a String method called getSideUp.

Coin class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Coin {
private String sideUp;

public Coin(){
    toss();
}

public void toss(){
    Random myRand = new Random();
    int face = myRand.nextInt(2);
    if(face == 0){
        sideUp = "heads";
    }
    else{
        sideUp = "tails";
    }
    getSideUp();
}
public String getSideUp(){
    return sideUp;

}
}
```

CoinDriver:

```
public class CoinDriver {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Coin coin = new Coin();
    int headsCount = 0;
    int tailsCount = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 40; i++){
        System.out.println(coin.getSideUp());
        if(coin.getSideUp().equals("heads")){
            headsCount++;
        }
        else if(coin.getSideUp().equals("tails")){
            tailsCount++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total number of heads: " + headsCount + "\nTotal number of tails: " + tailsCount);
}
}
```

Comment: That coin might be loaded ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only call `toss()` in the constructor, so nothing changes it once it has been created.

Call `toss()` on the `Coin` in the `for` loop to get a new result.

Comment: The problem is that toss() is a void type of method and you can't use that.

Comment: Sure, `toss()` returns `void`, but you are already calling `getSideUp()` in the `for` loop, just insert the call to `toss()` before that.  (And you don't need to call `getSideUp()` from with `toss()`; that does nothing useful.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the coin is re-tossed each time you iterate the body of the for-loop in `CoinDriver`. Try these instead:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Coin {

  public String toss() {
    Random myRand = new Random();
    int face = myRand.nextInt(2);
    if (face == 0) {
      return "heads";
    } else{
      return "tails";
    }       
  } 
}

public class CoinDriver {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Coin coin = new Coin();
    int headsCount = 0;
    int tailsCount = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {

      if (coin.toss().equals("heads")) {
        headsCount++;
      } else {
        tailsCount++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Total number of heads: " + headsCount + "\nTotal number of tails: " + tailsCount);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're better off re-using the same Random object for each toss. Random's default constructor uses the system clock to generate an initial seed; two Random objects created within the same clock tick are guaranteed to return the same sequence of values.

Comment: While this would work, I have been given a UML diagram that I must follow